# Is it legally OK to increase the weight of say a Times font by 10% and publish a book in the modified font?

Tags: fonts, legal

Say I am using Microsoft Word 2003 on Windows 10 Pro. Windows or perhaps Word (I am not sure which, but in any case they both originate from Microsoft) came bundled with several fonts in the Times type family. Although I have not actually found a copy of the licence, I suspect Microsoft allows me to

- use Word to write documents in Times
- "print" them as .pdfs, and
- send them to whoever I like (i.e. "publish" them).

My question is this: is it OK if I

- open a Times .ttf file in FontForge
- modify it by increasing the weight by say 10%
- print out some .pdfs, and then
- publish a book using those .pdfs (either an e-book put together from those .pdfs, or a hardcopy book that uses them as the camera-ready copy)

...just so long as I don't embed the modified font in any software I distribute or indeed make it available to anybody in .ttf or any other kind of standalone form? Just to be even clearer: the idea is that no copy of the modified font will ever leave the laptop that I have licences to run Windows and Word on, except for the backup I will keep on a flash drive.

Comment: Legal questions are off-topic here. Sorry about that. Ask your lawyer.

Comment: There's a `legal` tag, with [167 questions so far](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal).

Comment: See [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/119938/can-i-legally-use-fonts-for-my-personal-business-if-im-using-an-adobe-subscript), [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/117163/the-use-of-iconic-figures-in-a-logo), [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/116053/is-this-idea-about-font-licensing-true), [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/111602/client-asking-me-to-copy-another-website-layout-and-effects-but-not-content-wha), and many other questions tagged `legal` that have been answered and not objected to or closed.

Comment: Just because a tag exists, and some questions have been answered in the past and not closed doesn't make asking for legal advice on-topic. I answered one of these questions you linked to, but there's a disclaimer that it isn't legal advice. To be honest, if you reword this question so it's not a blatant request for legal advice, then it might be more acceptable.

Comment: Maybe you could ask something like: What are the potential legal implications of editing font software which is copyright?

Comment: Instead of altering the font file (which perhaps could be problematic, I really don't know), I guess you could just add stroke to the text in your layout program. I can't imagine adding stroke to a font would be against the law. But whatever twist and turns you make, I can't see how you could print a book without sending a PDF out in the world with the altered font.

Comment: Also, you should read the font licence, although these can be quite difficult to interpret sometimes, it might mean that what you are suggesting is a rather grey area. My gut reaction would be to avoid doing it, and perhaps find an Open SIL font instead which is similar to Times, but which you can legally modify.

Comment: @Billy - It's not true though that questions in the class "legal questions" are all off-topic here. When they read the words "increase the weight of say a Times font by 10%", I think most readers will understand that the question is intended to elicit answers that cover a more broader range of cases than just that specific one. Indeed that's not the specific issue that I have. By using the word "say" and making the question very easy to understand I was trying to make the question sufficiently general so that hopefully answers will also be more general and useful to more people.

Comment: You may well be right about it being sensible in practice to use some other font that's similar to Times and for which the position is totally clear.

Comment: @Wolff - So a .pdf made using a virtual printer such as say PDFCreator will always have any font used embedded in it, such that the .ttf file can in principle then be extracted by a person who only has the .pdf? If so, I think that answers the question.

Comment: OK here's my advice (not legal advice): Don't put yourself in positions like this without taking professional legal advice. Some things to consider: A judge will not care if you misunderstood a font licence, or didn't think you were doing anything wrong, or that some random (non-lawyer) person on GDSE said it was OK. Find an Open SIL font instead. Read the licence, and modify the font if the licence allows it.

Comment: @Billy - Many thanks for this. I think you're right. I checked with a font I made completely from scratch (not in breach of any licence) and then used in some .pdfs I printed using PDFCreator and in fact it is embedded in them. I personally don't know how to extract a .ttf from a .pdf but presumably some people do. Therefore for the Times-like project instead of using Times I will follow your advice and use something like Doulos or some other font distributed under the SIL OFL and hack it to my heart's content, always keeping to the terms of the OFL.

Comment: I'm **not** a lawyer -- but in *most* instances modifying a font for use within a PDF is nowhere near the same as modifying a font and then distributing the font files themselves. if I alter something locally, on my system, for my use, and *never* distribute the modification... that does not *necessarily* mean I'm infringing upon any copyrights. Matters may be entirely different if you modify Times **font files** and then distribute them *as a new font variant*. All this does beg the question.. why not simply use Times Bold? Or find a serif typeface which has Demi, Bold, and Black faces?

Comment: Traditionally if a font does not have the weight I want, my thought is *not* to alter the actual font files, but to find a font which *does* have the weights (and perhaps glyphs) I need.

Comment: "_I personally don't know how to extract a .ttf from a .pdf but presumably some people do._" I know now. FontForge can do it from its Open menu.